# Incompatible with parameter type of PVOID

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, detours

Using detours v3, I'm getting this error:

```
argument of type "signed int (Std::*)(int a1, int a2, int a3)" is incompatible with parameter of type "PVOID"   Std.cpp 39
```

When I try to use `DetourAttach` from a function on my class.

```
Std* _std = new Std();

case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)_std->m_pKey, &Std::m_Key);

// or if I do this
DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)_std->m_pKey, _std->m_Key);
// the error becomes Std::m_Key non-stardard syntax; use & to create a pointer to member
```

I know I can do this without using classes, but I wish to do so. Any suggestions?

---

Update

`DetourAttach` signature (can also be found [here](https://github.com/JaapSuter/Ten18/blob/master/lib/Detours%20Express%203.0/src/detours.cpp#L1389)):

```
LONG WINAPI DetourAttach(PVOID *ppPointer,
                         PVOID pDetour)
```

As for `Std::m_Key`

```
int Std::m_Key(int a1, int a2, int a3)
{
    return m_pKey(a1, a2, a3);
}
```

Comment: Provide some more info, please. What is the signature of `DetourAttach`? What is the type of `Std::m_Key`? What does `DetourAttach` do with its parameters, and what do you want to pass in? A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: &(PVOID&) is just plain wrong. It would mean you are passing a pointer to a reference to a pointer of type void

Answer (score 2):

This function signature is:

```
LONG DetourAttach(
    PVOID * ppPointer,
    PVOID pDetour
    );
```

first parameter is the pointer to a function to be `detoured`. The second one is your own function that will get called. As only single pointer can be provided you have no way of calling method on your class instance. To call a class instance method you need a pointer to your class object and a pointer to a method.

So you need a free function (non member) to make it work.

[edit]

Your free function can call you Std class instance method:

```
Std* _std = new Std();
int m_Global_Key(int a1, int a2, int a3)
{
    return _std->m_Key(a1, a2, a3);
}
```

Or you can make Std::m_Key, a static function, but it wont differ much from a global function.

Comment: Doing this gives me `& illegal operation on bound member function expression` and `DetourAttach function does not take 1 args`.

Comment: is m_Key a function? It looks as if it was a variable.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you need a global function, or static one to use DetourAttach.

Comment: Oh, right, it is `signed int __cdecl m_Key(int a1, int a2, int a3);`.

Comment: So, I should just get rid of the classes then? :D

Comment: You can have a global function which will call your _std->m_Key(...). Then use this global function as a second parameter to DetourAttach. But I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @majidarif: To use Detours, you need a solid grasp of how code works. In particular, things like the difference between an object and a class should be clear. When you pass a the address of member function to Detours, the class is implicit in the member function, but the object isn't. So you can't say " I wish to use classes"; you wish to use an object. _Exception_ : static methods don't need an object, but those would have worked.